# Wiring fan only

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

Removed the light unit from my ceiling fan. The wall switch controlled the light only, had to use pull chain to turn on fan. How do I wire the wall switch to control the fan.

Comment: Can you post a picture of the current wiring in the fan box without disconnecting anything?

Answer (score 1):

****This answer pertains to wire color coding for North American electrical Standards.****

You can re-wire the fan to make it simple. The fan will have to be opened-up at the ceiling cover-plate. Most wiring for ceiling fans are such that the blue wire from the FAN powers the light. This should be presently connected to the HOT (black) from the switch.

To power the fan simply remove the blue wire and attach the Black from the FAN to the Black from the wall switch.

Finally cap the Blue wire from the light. And remember that the pull chain switch must remain "on" for the wall switch to work.

Before starting any electrical work ensure that the breaker that controls the ceiling fan is OFF and Tagged if not in-line of sight from the work area.  Re-check at the fans ceiling box for no voltage on any of the present wires with a voltage tester.

Comment: note that this assumes us color coding.